# Prioritizing home DNS over public DNS?

Tags: networking, release-hera

I'm an elementary OS 5.1 user, and I self-host a few different applications including Jellyfin and Nextcloud on another Linux machine.

Because I didn't want to have to use a different endpoint URL for these applications at home than I do in public, in addition to a public DNS record with my domain registrar, I created a duplicate sort of DNS entry at home with my local DNS server.

For example:

jellyfin.example.com resolves to 192.168.1.101 when using local DNS server.

jellyfin.example.com resolves to 75.74.73.72 when using public DNS server.

My issue is that when I first connect to my home network, it is resolved locally as I expect. After about 15 minutes or so, it switches to being resolved publicly, which then cuts off my ability to access using the fully-qualified domain name. It continuously switches back and forth every few minutes. As of right now, I have no clue why.

How can I tell elementary OS to use the local DNS server when I'm at home, and the public DNS server otherwise?